# I am new and I would like to know how to go from string to json please?

Tags: python

```py
username = request.json['username']
  
output = subprocess.check_output("python3 sherlock.py "+username, shell=True)
rso = str(output).split(sep='Input')[0]
        
buffer = []
        
for item in output:
    tmp = str(item).split("\\n")
            
    tmp2 = {
        tmp[0].replace((': ','":"')):tmp[1].replace(" ", "")
    }
    buffer.append(tmp2)
      
    print(rso)
    return jsonify({"msg":str(buffer)})
```

this is the result that I have to convert:

```
{
    "msg": "b'[*] Checking username aylinmari_ on:\\n[+] CapFriendly: https://www.capfriendly.com/users/aylinmari_\\n[+] Codecademy: https://www.codecademy.com/profiles/aylinmari_\\n[+] Coil: https://coil.com/u/aylinmari_\\n[+] Facenama: https://facenama.com/aylinmari_\\n[+] Fiverr: https://www.fiverr.com/aylinmari_\\n"
}
```

This is `sherlock.py`:

```
import csv
import os
import platform
import re
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser, RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
from time import monotonic
import requests
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
from torrequest import TorRequest
from result import QueryStatus
from result import QueryResult
from notify import QueryNotifyPrint
from sites  import SitesInformation

module_name = "Sherlock: Find Usernames Across Social Networks"
__version__ = "0.14.0"




class SherlockFuturesSession(FuturesSession):
    def request(self, method, url, hooks={}, *args, **kwargs):
        """Request URL.

        This extends the FuturesSession request method to calculate a response
        time metric to each request.

        It is taken (almost) directly from the following StackOverflow answer:
        https://github.com/ross/requests-futures#working-in-the-background

        Keyword Arguments:
        self                   -- This object.
        method                 -- String containing method desired for request.
        url                    -- String containing URL for request.
        hooks                  -- Dictionary containing hooks to execute after
                                  request finishes.
        args                   -- Arguments.
        kwargs                 -- Keyword arguments.

        Return Value:
        Request object.
        """
        # Record the start time for the request.
        start = monotonic()

        def response_time(resp, *args, **kwargs):
            """Response Time Hook.

            Keyword Arguments:
            resp                   -- Response object.
            args                   -- Arguments.
            kwargs                 -- Keyword arguments.

            Return Value:
            N/A
            """
            resp.elapsed = monotonic() - start

            return

        # Install hook to execute when response completes.
        # Make sure that the time measurement hook is first, so we will not
        # track any later hook's execution time.
        try:
            if isinstance(hooks['response'], list):
                hooks['response'].insert(0, response_time)
            elif isinstance(hooks['response'], tuple):
                # Convert tuple to list and insert time measurement hook first.
                hooks['response'] = list(hooks['response'])
                hooks['response'].insert(0, response_time)
            else:
                # Must have previously contained a single hook function,
                # so convert to list.
                hooks['response'] = [response_time, hooks['response']]
        except KeyError:
            # No response hook was already defined, so install it ourselves.
            hooks['response'] = [response_time]

        return super(SherlockFuturesSession, self).request(method,
                                                           url,
                                                           hooks=hooks,
                                                           *args, **kwargs)


def get_response(request_future, error_type, social_network):

    # Default for Response object if some failure occurs.
    response = None

    error_context = "General Unknown Error"
    expection_text = None
    try:
        response = request_future.result()
        if response.status_code:
            # Status code exists in response object
            error_context = None
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        error_context = "HTTP Error"
        expection_text = str(errh)
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError as errp:
        error_context = "Proxy Error"
        expection_text = str(errp)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        error_context = "Error Connecting"
        expection_text = str(errc)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        error_context = "Timeout Error"
        expection_text = str(errt)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        error_context = "Unknown Error"
        expection_text = str(err)

    return response, error_context, expection_text

def sherlock(username, site_data, query_notify,
             tor=False, unique_tor=False,
             proxy=None, timeout=None):
    """Run Sherlock Analysis.

    Checks for existence of username on various social media sites.

    Keyword Arguments:
    username               -- String indicating username that report
                              should be created against.
    site_data              -- Dictionary containing all of the site data.
    query_notify           -- Object with base type of QueryNotify().
                              This will be used to notify the caller about
                              query results.
    tor                    -- Boolean indicating whether to use a tor circuit for the requests.
    unique_tor             -- Boolean indicating whether to use a new tor circuit for each request.
    proxy                  -- String indicating the proxy URL
    timeout                -- Time in seconds to wait before timing out request.
                              Default is no timeout.

    Return Value:
    Dictionary containing results from report. Key of dictionary is the name
    of the social network site, and the value is another dictionary with
    the following keys:
        url_main:      URL of main site.
        url_user:      URL of user on site (if account exists).
        status:        QueryResult() object indicating results of test for
                       account existence.
        http_status:   HTTP status code of query which checked for existence on
                       site.
        response_text: Text that came back from request.  May be None if
                       there was an HTTP error when checking for existence.
    """

    # Notify caller that we are starting the query.
    query_notify.start(username)

    # Create session based on request methodology
    if tor or unique_tor:
        # Requests using Tor obfuscation
        underlying_request = TorRequest()
        underlying_session = underlying_request.session
    else:
        # Normal requests
        underlying_session = requests.session()
        underlying_request = requests.Request()

    # Limit number of workers to 20.
    # This is probably vastly overkill.
    if len(site_data) >= 20:
        max_workers=20
    else:
        max_workers=len(site_data)

    # Create multi-threaded session for all requests.
    session = SherlockFuturesSession(max_workers=max_workers,
                                     session=underlying_session)


    # Results from analysis of all sites
    results_total = {}

    # First create futures for all requests. This allows for the requests to run in parallel
    for social_network, net_info in site_data.items():

        # Results from analysis of this specific site
        results_site = {}

        # Record URL of main site
        results_site['url_main'] = net_info.get("urlMain")

        # A user agent is needed because some sites don't return the correct
        # information since they think that we are bots (Which we actually are...)
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0',
        }

        if "headers" in net_info:
            # Override/append any extra headers required by a given site.
            headers.update(net_info["headers"])

        # URL of user on site (if it exists)
        url = net_info["url"].format(username)

        # Don't make request if username is invalid for the site
        regex_check = net_info.get("regexCheck")
        if regex_check and re.search(regex_check, username) is None:
            # No need to do the check at the site: this user name is not allowed.
            results_site['status'] = QueryResult(username,
                                                 social_network,
                                                 url,
                                                 QueryStatus.ILLEGAL)
            results_site["url_user"] = ""
            results_site['http_status'] = ""
            results_site['response_text'] = ""
            query_notify.update(results_site['status'])
        else:
            # URL of user on site (if it exists)
            results_site["url_user"] = url
            url_probe = net_info.get("urlProbe")
            if url_probe is None:
                # Probe URL is normal one seen by people out on the web.
                url_probe = url
            else:
                # There is a special URL for probing existence separate
                # from where the user profile normally can be found.
                url_probe = url_probe.format(username)

            if (net_info["errorType"] == 'status_code' and
                net_info.get("request_head_only", True) == True):
                # In most cases when we are detecting by status code,
                # it is not necessary to get the entire body:  we can
                # detect fine with just the HEAD response.
                request_method = session.head
            else:
                # Either this detect method needs the content associated
                # with the GET response, or this specific website will
                # not respond properly unless we request the whole page.
                request_method = session.get

            if net_info["errorType"] == "response_url":
                # Site forwards request to a different URL if username not
                # found.  Disallow the redirect so we can capture the
                # http status from the original URL request.
                allow_redirects = False
            else:
                # Allow whatever redirect that the site wants to do.
                # The final result of the request will be what is available.
                allow_redirects = True

            # This future starts running the request in a new thread, doesn't block the main thread
            if proxy is not None:
                proxies = {"http": proxy, "https": proxy}
                future = request_method(url=url_probe, headers=headers,
                                        proxies=proxies,
                                        allow_redirects=allow_redirects,
                                        timeout=timeout
                                        )
            else:
                future = request_method(url=url_probe, headers=headers,
                                        allow_redirects=allow_redirects,
                                        timeout=timeout
                                        )

            # Store future in data for access later
            net_info["request_future"] = future

            # Reset identify for tor (if needed)
            if unique_tor:
                underlying_request.reset_identity()

        # Add this site's results into final dictionary with all of the other results.
        results_total[social_network] = results_site

    # Open the file containing account links
    # Core logic: If tor requests, make them here. If multi-threaded requests, wait for responses
    for social_network, net_info in site_data.items():

        # Retrieve results again
        results_site = results_total.get(social_network)

        # Retrieve other site information again
        url = results_site.get("url_user")
        status = results_site.get("status")
        if status is not None:
            # We have already determined the user doesn't exist here
            continue

        # Get the expected error type
        error_type = net_info["errorType"]

        # Retrieve future and ensure it has finished
        future = net_info["request_future"]
        r, error_text, expection_text = get_response(request_future=future,
                                                     error_type=error_type,
                                                     social_network=social_network)

        # Get response time for response of our request.
        try:
            response_time = r.elapsed
        except AttributeError:
            response_time = None

        # Attempt to get request information
        try:
            http_status = r.status_code
        except:
            http_status = "?"
        try:
            response_text = r.text.encode(r.encoding)
        except:
            response_text = ""

        if error_text is not None:
            result = QueryResult(username,
                                 social_network,
                                 url,
                                 QueryStatus.UNKNOWN,
                                 query_time=response_time,
                                 context=error_text)
        elif error_type == "message":
            # error_flag True denotes no error found in the HTML
            # error_flag False denotes error found in the HTML
            error_flag = True
            errors=net_info.get("errorMsg")
            # errors will hold the error message
            # it can be string or list
            # by insinstance method we can detect that
            # and handle the case for strings as normal procedure
            # and if its list we can iterate the errors
            if isinstance(errors,str):
                # Checks if the error message is in the HTML
                # if error is present we will set flag to False
                if errors in r.text:
                    error_flag = False
            else:
                # If it's list, it will iterate all the error message
                for error in errors:
                    if error in r.text:
                        error_flag = False
                        break
            if error_flag:
                result = QueryResult(username,
                                     social_network,
                                     url,
                                     QueryStatus.CLAIMED,
                                     query_time=response_time)
            else:
                result = QueryResult(username,
                                     social_network,
                                     url,
                                     QueryStatus.AVAILABLE,
                                     query_time=response_time)
        elif error_type == "status_code":
            # Checks if the status code of the response is 2XX
            if not r.status_code >= 300 or r.status_code < 200:
                result = QueryResult(username,
                                     social_network,
                                     url,
                                     QueryStatus.CLAIMED,
                                     query_time=response_time)
            else:
                result = QueryResult(username,
                                     social_network,
                                     url,
                                     QueryStatus.AVAILABLE,
                                     query_time=response_time)
        elif error_type == "response_url":
            # For this detection method, we have turned off the redirect.
            # So, there is no need to check the response URL: it will always
            # match the request.  Instead, we will ensure that the response
            # code indicates that the request was successful (i.e. no 404, or
            # forward to some odd redirect).
            if 200 <= r.status_code < 300:
                result = QueryResult(username,
                                     social_network,
                                     url,
                                     QueryStatus.CLAIMED,
                                     query_time=response_time)
            else:
                result = QueryResult(username,
                                     social_network,
                                     url,
                                     QueryStatus.AVAILABLE,
                                     query_time=response_time)
        else:
            # It should be impossible to ever get here...
            raise ValueError(f"Unknown Error Type '{error_type}' for "
                             f"site '{social_network}'")


        # Notify caller about results of query.
        query_notify.update(result)

        # Save status of request
        results_site['status'] = result

        # Save results from request
        results_site['http_status'] = http_status
        results_site['response_text'] = response_text

        # Add this site's results into final dictionary with all of the other results.
        results_total[social_network] = results_site

    # Notify caller that all queries are finished.
    query_notify.finish()

    return results_total

def timeout_check(value):
    """Check Timeout Argument.

    Checks timeout for validity.

    Keyword Arguments:
    value                  -- Time in seconds to wait before timing out request.

    Return Value:
    Floating point number representing the time (in seconds) that should be
    used for the timeout.

    NOTE:  Will raise an exception if the timeout in invalid.
    """
    from argparse import ArgumentTypeError

    try:
        timeout = float(value)
    except:
        raise ArgumentTypeError(f"Timeout '{value}' must be a number.")
    if timeout <= 0:
        raise ArgumentTypeError(f"Timeout '{value}' must be greater than 0.0s.")
    return timeout


def main():

    version_string = f"%(prog)s {__version__}\n" +  \
                     f"{requests.__description__}:  {requests.__version__}\n" + \
                     f"Python:  {platform.python_version()}"

    parser = ArgumentParser(formatter_class=RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                            description=f"{module_name} (Version {__version__})"
                            )
    parser.add_argument("--version",
                        action="version",  version=version_string,
                        help="Display version information and dependencies."
                        )
    parser.add_argument("--verbose", "-v", "-d", "--debug",
                        action="store_true",  dest="verbose", default=False,
                        help="Display extra debugging information and metrics."
                        )
    parser.add_argument("--folderoutput", "-fo", dest="folderoutput",
                        help="If using multiple usernames, the output of the results will be saved to this folder."
                        )
    parser.add_argument("--output", "-o", dest="output",
                        help="If using single username, the output of the result will be saved to this file."
                        )
    parser.add_argument("--tor", "-t",
                        action="store_true", dest="tor", default=False,
                        help="Make requests over Tor; increases runtime; requires Tor to be installed and in system path.")
    parser.add_argument("--unique-tor", "-u",
                        action="store_true", dest="unique_tor", default=False,
                        help="Make requests over Tor with new Tor circuit after each request; increases runtime; requires Tor to be installed and in system path.")
    parser.add_argument("--csv",
                        action="store_true",  dest="csv", default=False,
                        help="Create Comma-Separated Values (CSV) File."
                        )
    parser.add_argument("--site",
                        action="append", metavar='SITE_NAME',
                        dest="site_list", default=None,
                        help="Limit analysis to just the listed sites. Add multiple options to specify more than one site."
                        )
    parser.add_argument("--proxy", "-p", metavar='PROXY_URL',
                        action="store", dest="proxy", default=None,
                        help="Make requests over a proxy. e.g. socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
                        )
    parser.add_argument("--json", "-j", metavar="JSON_FILE",
                        dest="json_file", default=None,
                        help="Load data from a JSON file or an online, valid, JSON file.")
    parser.add_argument("--timeout",
                        action="store", metavar='TIMEOUT',
                        dest="timeout", type=timeout_check, default=None,
                        help="Time (in seconds) to wait for response to requests. "
                             "Default timeout is infinity. "
                             "A longer timeout will be more likely to get results from slow sites. "
                             "On the other hand, this may cause a long delay to gather all results."
                       )
    parser.add_argument("--print-all",
                        action="store_true", dest="print_all",
                        help="Output sites where the username was not found."
                       )
    parser.add_argument("--print-found",
                        action="store_false", dest="print_all", default=False,
                        help="Output sites where the username was found."
                       )
    parser.add_argument("--no-color",
                        action="store_true", dest="no_color", default=False,
                        help="Don't color terminal output"
                        )
    parser.add_argument("username",
                        nargs='+', metavar='USERNAMES',
                        action="store",
                        help="One or more usernames to check with social networks."
                        )
    parser.add_argument("--browse", "-b",
                        action="store_true", dest="browse", default=False,
                        help="Browse to all results on default browser.")

    parser.add_argument("--local", "-l",
                        action="store_true", default=False,
                        help="Force the use of the local data.json file.")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Check for newer version of Sherlock. If it exists, let the user know about it
    try:
        r = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sherlock-project/sherlock/master/sherlock/sherlock.py")

        remote_version = str(re.findall('__version__ = "(.*)"', r.text)[0])
        local_version = __version__

        if remote_version != local_version:
            print("Update Available!\n" +
                  f"You are running version {local_version}. Version {remote_version} is available at https://git.io/sherlock")

    except Exception as error:
        print(f"A problem occured while checking for an update: {error}")

    # Argument check
    # TODO regex check on args.proxy
    if args.tor and (args.proxy is not None):
        raise Exception("Tor and Proxy cannot be set at the same time.")

    # Make prompts
    if args.proxy is not None:
        print("Using the proxy: " + args.proxy)

    if args.tor or args.unique_tor:
        print("Using Tor to make requests")
        print("Warning: some websites might refuse connecting over Tor, so note that using this option might increase connection errors.")

    # Check if both output methods are entered as input.
    if args.output is not None and args.folderoutput is not None:
        print("You can only use one of the output methods.")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Check validity for single username output.
    if args.output is not None and len(args.username) != 1:
        print("You can only use --output with a single username")
        sys.exit(1)


    # Create object with all information about sites we are aware of.
    try:
        if args.local:
            sites = SitesInformation(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'resources/data.json'))
        else:
            sites = SitesInformation(args.json_file)
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"ERROR:  {error}")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Create original dictionary from SitesInformation() object.
    # Eventually, the rest of the code will be updated to use the new object
    # directly, but this will glue the two pieces together.
    site_data_all = {}
    for site in sites:
        site_data_all[site.name] = site.information

    if args.site_list is None:
        # Not desired to look at a sub-set of sites
        site_data = site_data_all
    else:
        # User desires to selectively run queries on a sub-set of the site list.

        # Make sure that the sites are supported & build up pruned site database.
        site_data = {}
        site_missing = []
        for site in args.site_list:
            counter = 0
            for existing_site in site_data_all:
                if site.lower() == existing_site.lower():
                    site_data[existing_site] = site_data_all[existing_site]
                    counter += 1
            if counter == 0:
                # Build up list of sites not supported for future error message.
                site_missing.append(f"'{site}'")

        if site_missing:
            print(f"Error: Desired sites not found: {', '.join(site_missing)}.")

        if not site_data:
            sys.exit(1)

    # Create notify object for query results.
    query_notify = QueryNotifyPrint(result=None,
                                    verbose=args.verbose,
                                    print_all=args.print_all,
                                    color=not args.no_color)

    # Run report on all specified users.
    for username in args.username:
        results = sherlock(username,
                           site_data,
                           query_notify,
                           tor=args.tor,
                           unique_tor=args.unique_tor,
                           proxy=args.proxy,
                           timeout=args.timeout)

        if args.output:
            result_file = args.output
        elif args.folderoutput:
            # The usernames results should be stored in a targeted folder.
            # If the folder doesn't exist, create it first
            os.makedirs(args.folderoutput, exist_ok=True)
            result_file = os.path.join(args.folderoutput, f"{username}.txt")
        else:
            result_file = f"{username}.txt"

        with open(result_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            exists_counter = 0
            for website_name in results:
                dictionary = results[website_name]
                if dictionary.get("status").status == QueryStatus.CLAIMED:
                    exists_counter += 1
                    file.write(dictionary["url_user"] + "\n")
            file.write(f"Total Websites Username Detected On : {exists_counter}\n")

        if args.csv:
            result_file = f"{username}.csv"
            if args.folderoutput:
                # The usernames results should be stored in a targeted folder.
                # If the folder doesn't exist, create it first
                os.makedirs(args.folderoutput, exist_ok=True)
                result_file = os.path.join(args.folderoutput, result_file)

            with open(result_file, "w", newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csv_report:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_report)
                writer.writerow(['username',
                                 'name',
                                 'url_main',
                                 'url_user',
                                 'exists',
                                 'http_status',
                                 'response_time_s'
                                 ]
                                )
                for site in results:
                    response_time_s = results[site]['status'].query_time
                    if response_time_s is None:
                        response_time_s = ""
                    writer.writerow([username,
                                     site,
                                     results[site]['url_main'],
                                     results[site]['url_user'],
                                     str(results[site]['status'].status),
                                     results[site]['http_status'],
                                     response_time_s
                                     ]
                                    )
        print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: All of the links provided are broken

Comment: `output` is a byte string. So `for item in output:` is iterating over the individual bytes.

Comment: Putting `return` inside the `for` loop makes it stop after the first iteration.

Comment: Maybe you should be looping over `rso`?

Comment: Can you show the value of `rso`?

Comment: @Barmar "rso" is just the name of the variable that shows the "output" with the subprocess

Comment: I know. That's what I want to see.

Comment: I just want that result to be as key: value inside an array, but I don't know how to do it, please

Comment: @Barmar what would be necessary for the result to arrive in this way:
vart = [{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value"}],
please

Comment: Since I don't know what the original data looks like, I have no idea how to transform it to that form.

Comment: Where do the keys and values come from in the output of the command?

Comment: Is sherlock.py from [this](https://sherlock-project.github.io/)?

Comment: @Barmar is the result of a request sent with postman, so it returns the result

Comment: @Barmar yes and the output is from sherlock.py

Comment: You're not helping. I need to see an actual example of the output, so I can understand what you're trying to convert.

Comment: There's a demo [here](https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock) but I don't see `Input` anywhere in the output. What is that split supposed to do?

Comment: Why have you escaped the backslash here: `split("\\n")`?

Comment: @Barmar is what I want to separate, the result that is at the end is what postman returns, a string that I must pass to an array of key: value.

Comment: @Barmar just the example you show me is the output that is in my code

Comment: @Barmar this string is the one I want to arrive as key: value in an array:

Comment: { "msg": "b '[*] Checking username aylinmari_ on: \\ n [+] CapFriendly: https://www.capfriendly.com/users/aylinmari_\\n[+] Codecademy: https: // www. codecademy.com/profiles/aylinmari_\\n[+] Coil: https://coil.com/u/aylinmari_\\n[+] Facenama: https://facenama.com/aylinmari_\\n[+] Fiverr : https://www.fiverr.com/aylinmari_\\n "}

Comment: I know what you want in the result. I want to see the value of `output` so I can see where those strings should come from, and how you can make it look like that.

Comment: Put it in the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: @Barmar I already updated with the output code

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like what I see in the video. But I've posted an answer anyway.

Comment: You posted the entire sherlock.py instead of a sample of the output.

Comment: BTW, sherlock.py has a `--csv` option. Wouldn't it be easier to use that output instead of the human-oriented output?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at a sample output of `sherlock.py` at https://asciinema.org/a/223115, I don't see why you're doing any splitting. You should just search for `[*] Checking username` and get everything from there, to skip over the picture of Sherlock.

```
import re

username = request.json['username']
  
output = subprocess.check_output("python3 sherlock.py "+username, shell=True)
lines = re.sub(r'^.*?(?=\[\*\] Checking username)', '', flags=re.DOTALL)

return jsonify({"msg": lines})
```